# Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.set: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am getting this exception in my background.html page. I don't know what this exception says. Can anyone explain this exception and also tell me how to resolve this exception.

The exception details are

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.set: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded
```

Thank you.

Comment: Even without looking at documentation, I'd guess "`storage ... BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded`" is saying you're trying to store too large of an object under a single key.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved my issue by using chrome.storage.local  5,242,880 QUOTA_BYTES. This solved my problem.  The maximum amount (in bytes) of data that can be stored in local storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of every value plus every key's length. This value will be ignored if the extension has the unlimitedStorage permission

Answer (score 57):

> This error comes when you use **chrome.storage.sync.set**...to set the data greater than 8,192 bytes for a single item as chrome.storage.sync.set allows **8,192 QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM**.

Use chrome.storage.local.set, to save the large data...instead of chrome.storage.sync.set.
As **chrome.storage.local.set** can contains **5242880 :QUOTA_BYTES**.

See **https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage**

Also, you can get the alert if still want to use chrome.storage.sync.set using below code:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set(function() {  
   var error = chrome.runtime.lastError;  
   if (error) {  
      alert(error);  
   }  
});
```

If you are getting same **warning with chrome.storage.local** too, then

**Reason**: The data you are trying to store is greater than the allowed storage with local i.e. 5242880 QUOTA_BYTES.
**Solution**: You can set the **permission as unlimitedStorage in manifest.json file**.

```
  "permissions": [   
    .....  
    "unlimitedStorage",  
    .....  
   ],
```

For more regarding permission
1) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-managed
2) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning

Comment: Use permission as unlimitedStorage in menifest file. Check both URLs: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions    
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning

Comment: unlimitedStorage doesn't fix the problem,

Comment: @titusfx, can you send me screenshots of code permission, file, where you are using this.

Comment: user chrome.storage.local.set in place of chrome.storage.sync.set

Comment: @ShivSingh, Hey, I think you didn't read complete solution. Kindly read it...it is the same as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

As outlined by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) in his comment above, the answer is covered in the [chrome.storage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-sync).

Moreover, it's always a good practice to implement error handling and check for `runtime.lastError`. If everything is all right, it will be undefined. If there is a problem, it will be non-empty, and `chrome.runtime.lastError.message` will explain what's wrong.

Chrome added checks that `chrome.runtime.lastError` is actually checked (evaluated). If not, it considers this to be an unhandled exception, and throws this error.